# How do I update my rooted Samsung galaxy s4?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, unrooting

This is a complex question for me so I appreciate anyone helping me through it. I have a galaxy s4 that hasn't been updated since purchase b/c I was afraid to lose root.

I'm in the process of backing everything up now.

My concerns are...

1 Should I unroot? Will I screw up unrooting. I'm not familiar with the latest tools available and I don't know if it's necessary b/c...

2 I assume I can just do a factory reset and that will negate the need to unroot? Am I wrong?

3 Again I assume after doing the factory reset I can do the updates via my device OTA. Here's my most significant concern, that I shouldn't do all the updates b/c the most recent update has somehow thwarted whatever rooting tools might be currently available.

4 reroot, install a current ROM, reset up device.

I've done this a number of times with a number of devices but I haven't done it since I got this galaxy s4 shortly after release. That's how long it's been. I know there are tutorials and videos and tools and forums but I think I have some unique issues and context here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: They are not unique issues. :D For 2) and 3): `su` binary (allows access to root user) is located inside `/system` and not `/data` or `/cache`. When you factory reset, only `/data` and `/cache` (and optionally, your internal SD card too) is cleared. In that way, the app managing root access would be lost (if you didn't make it system app already) but `su` binary would remain in the `/system`. Hence, if you attempt OTA,  system integrity would be found lost and so, OTA would not proceed IMO (it's theoretical for me; I never do OTA updates).

Comment: As a fellow Galaxy S4 owner myself I would consider just changing the rom you are running. No need for the official samsung firmware if not otherwise specified. When you want to install an AOSP based rom(which I strongly suggest because of the newer android version) : 1) no need to update your stock firmware 2)go to the corresponding xda forum and look for "Original Android Development". If you want to run a Samsung Touchwiz based rom then look for the "Android Development" forum and check if you need to update your bootloader/modem to work well with the new rom.